# report requirement of new share offering

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

When a public company offers new shares, does it have to notify SEC by filing a report?

For example, if the company just gives its employees some shares, does it have to report it to SEC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A secondary share offering is disclosed in SEC form S-3.

For employee compensation, the company may disclose equity compensation plans and executive contracts in their usual quarterly filings. Insider transactions are disclosed with [Form 4](https://www.sec.gov/files/forms-3-4-5.pdf). (PDF)